# Perform action when button clicked once and do a different action when clicked twice, three times etc. (Netbeans, Java)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, desktop

I am fairly new to Java programming and want to make a basic game that shows an image when clicked once, a different image when clicked twice and etc.
I know how to do all this but I don't know how to keep track of how any clicks and then do an actions based on how many clicks have been done (Hard to explain, my apologies...)

Comment: Use a counter int variable that you increment when the button is clicked, and base the image (or better, ImageIcon) shown based on the value of the counter. To better be able to help you, let's see your attempt to do this, your code, so that we can better understand your problems and be able to give you *specific* advice rather than this general advice.

Comment: Clicks only count the events occurred in the source of event, if you click once or double-click is the kind of click you count once the others are counted twice.

Answer (score 1):

> I ... want to make a basic game that shows an image when clicked once, a different image when clicked twice and etc. I know how to do all this but I don't know how to keep track of how any clicks

As per my comment, give the class with the ActionListener an int field, say called buttonCount, and increment it each time the button is pressed -- inside of the button ActionListener's actionPerformed method: `buttonCount++`

> and then do an actions based on how many clicks have been done (Hard to explain, my apologies...)

In the ActionListener's actionPerformed method change the image displayed. How you change it all depends on how you show it, something that you've yet to show us, and so I can't give you any code.

One way to make it easy is to create an ArrayList of ImageIcons to hold your images (as ImageIcons of course), and then call `get(buttonCount)` on the ArrayList to get the appropriate ImageIcon and display it in a JLabel via its `setIcon(...)` method. Make sure that the buttonCount is less than the size of the ArrayList so as not to get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. One way to do this is to mod your buttonCount by the size of the ArrayList. This will allow you to cycle through your collection of images.

Again, you will want to read the Swing tutorials on [how to use JButtons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and then break down your big problem into small steps, trying to solve each step one at a time.

Again if you need greater detail and more specific help, then you must show what you've tried and explain in detail what problems you may be having with it. It is my sincere believe and philosophy that you learn most by by forcing your brain to do new and unfamiliar things, by mental effort and sweat. So have at it, you've nothing to lose.

Answer (score -1):

You can count the the mouse clicks in this way. By using an if-else or switch case you can display the images.

```
public class ButtonStart extends Frame {
private int mouseclicked = 0;
TextField objTextField;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    ButtonStart BS = new ButtonStart();
}

public ButtonStart() {
    Frame objFrame;
    Button objButton;
    TextField objTextField;
    objFrame = new Frame("Clicking Buttons");
    objButton = new Button("Click me!");
    objTextField = new TextField("0");

    objFrame.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
    objFrame.add(objButton);
    objFrame.add(objTextField);
    objFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()

    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

}

public class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        int mouseclicked = me.getClickCount();

        objTextField.setText("Mouse clicked this many times:"
                + mouseclicked);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: AWT? MouseListener? Absolute positioning? Original poster, please don't follow this poster's advice. He meant well, but it is poor. Again, I recommend that you (the original poster) post *your* code and let's see if we can help you with the problems in your code, not in this code above.

Comment: I'm a beginner and just wanted to do this as a way of practicing. To be honest, there is no code to show anyone, because I have no clue how to do this specific thing.

Comment: @user2864152: You need to read the Swing tutorials on [how to use JButtons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and then break down your big problem into small steps, trying to solve each step one at a time. Then come back if your attempt doesn't work. But again, don't use any of the code posted by user.